# For Loops Not Working

Tags: javascript

Hi I have created a for loop like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
    array = {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
    testarray = [array];
}
```

It doesnt seem to work, I cant find the error it is giving either because I am running it on the web and when i like in the source it is in a weird format.

Basically All I am trying to do is this:

```
array1 = {x: xAxis[0], y: yAxis[0], value: (count[0] / average * 100)};
array2 = {x: xAxis[1], y: yAxis[1], value: (count[1] / average * 100)};
array3 = {x: xAxis[2], y: yAxis[2], value: (count[2] / average * 100)};
array4 = {x: xAxis[3], y: yAxis[3], value: (count[3] / average * 100)};
array5 = {x: xAxis[4], y: yAxis[4], value: (count[4] / average * 100)};
array6 = {x: xAxis[5], y: yAxis[5], value: (count[5] / average * 100)};

var testarray = [array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, array6];
```

But using a loop instead and I dont know how to make it work. The variables are working so I know that is the format I need it in but when I tried creating it using a loop instead it crashed.

Comment: Can you try for (var i = 0....

Comment: Declare `testarray = []` before loop and use `testarray.push(array)`. `var testarray = [];
for (i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) {
    array = {
        x: xAxis[i],
        y: yAxis[i],
        value: (count[i] / average * 100)
    };

    testarray.push(array);
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `testarray = [array];` use `push`:

```
testarray.push(array);
```

Of course for this you need to initialize the array beforehand, so before your for-loop add this:

```
var testarray = [];
```

What you were doing was reassigning your `testarray` to a different array for each iteration of the loop. `push` adds an element to your array instead.

So put together your code should look like this:

```
var testarray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
    var array = {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
    testarray.push(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
    var testarray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
        var array = {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
        testarray.push(array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined testarray. Also - you don't use curly braces for aray - so best to not use array for the name:

```
var testarray=[];
for (i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
        item= {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
    testarray.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use push property of array to insert new element into the array

use this code, this will surely work:-

```
var testarray = [];
var array = {};
for (var i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
    array = {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
    testarray.push(array);
}
```